# Hashcode value for Map Entry

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode, hash-code-uniqueness

As per javadocs hashcode for a map.entry is defined as :

```
int hashCode()
  Returns the hash code value for this map entry. The hash code of a map entry e is defined to be:
    (e.getKey()==null   ? 0 : e.getKey().hashCode()) ^
    (e.getValue()==null ? 0 : e.getValue().hashCode())
```

Plz confirm, if a bitwise XOR operator is used for calculating the hashcode value for a map entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it indeed is a bitwise XOR operator. I tried & got the same result for both the hashcode() method & by using ^ operator.

```
import java.util.*;
class TreeMapExample {
public static void main(String args[]) {
 // Creating TreeMap object
 TreeMap<String, Integer> tm = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
 // Adding elements to the Map
 tm.put("Chaitanya", 27);
 tm.put("Raghu", 35);
 tm.put("Rajeev", 37);
 tm.put("Syed", 28);
 tm.put("Hugo", 32);

 // Getting a set of the entries
 Set set = tm.entrySet();
 // Get an iterator
 Iterator it = set.iterator();
 // Display elements
 int hash;
 while(it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println("Key: "+me.getKey() + " & Value: "+me.getValue());
    System.out.println("hashcode value by method : "+me.hashCode());
    hash = me.getKey().hashCode() ^ me.getValue().hashCode();
    System.out.println("hashcode value by operator : "+me.hashCode()+"\n");
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the actual code taken from the `Map.Entry` as defined in the `HashMap` implementation.  The `^` operator is the exclusive OR operator for Java.

```
public final int hashCode() {
       return Objects.hashCode(key) ^ Objects.hashCode(value);
}
```

However, the method of computation or specific result should be of no consequence to the user as long as the contract for `hashCode` is satisfied.

Comment: On the contrary, that would be a breaking change to a core Java API (and would have to be replaced with something just as arbitrary). `Map.Entry` is implemented in dozens of libraries; it's not going to change.

Comment: IDK from where you get the actual code. But here is the link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#hashCode--

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-  I was focusing more on from the user's perspective than the API developer's.  But I modified my statement  based on your comment.  Thanks!

Comment: @AbhishekRaj  The source is in `src.zip` in the `jdk-<version>\lib` directory.  At least when downloaded from Oracle or one of their mirrors.  If you use an IDE (I use Eclipse) there should be a way of linking it to your IDE so that you can bring up the source for any class in the API (at least most of the classes).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `^` means 'XOR'. [Here is a list of all operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html).

This sure seems like something a web search would have found a lot faster than asking an SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, hashCode() for Map.Entry returns the bitwise XOR of the hashCodes of the key and value.

**Incorrect explanation - left in place for context so comments below make sense**

> This ensures that two instances of a Map.Entry object which have the same hashCode() value are guaranteed to have equal Key and Value properties. (Assuming the hashCode() method is properly overridden in both the Types used as Key and Value)

Comment: This is utter hogwash, of course. Mathematically provable, even: There are only 2^32 = 4 billion different hashcodes (as the `hashCode()` method returns an `int`, and it is limited in that manner). There are more strings than that (turn every number between 0 and 8 billion into a string, and there you have it). Strings are objects, and can be placed in hashmaps. Apply pigeon hole principle. QED.

Comment: For any `hashCode()` of two objects, identical hash codes never imply equal objects.  But equal objects as defined by `equals()` must have the same hash code. And two objects that are unequal may also have the same hash code but it is not guaranteed (a different way of saying the first sentence).

Comment: @rzwitserloot and WJS, thank you for the corrections. I might have gotten a bit carried away there! Probably should have left my answer as a simple ‘yes’